# Is it a bad practice to use service layer in domain layer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, amazon-s3

I'm using Spring, JPA and AWS S3 services.

In my project...
There is an `S3Service` class in the service layer.
There is an `image` class in the domain layer which has an attribute of the name of the image file on S3.

The related S3 files should be deleted whenever the tuples of the image table are deleted from the database.
So, I want to use `@PreRemove` annotation in `image` so that the image can use the delete method of the `S3Service` before being removed.

Is it a bad practice to access service layer in domain layer?
If so, how could I delete S3 files when the tuples are deleted?

Comment: IMHO the S3Service is not a service but an integration class that would be on the same layer as your repositories.

Comment: How is the data deleted from the DB table? Is it done via a Repository called by a Service?

Comment: @JoãoDias By JPA. Cascade.REMOVE option or orphanRemoval=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the Service that removes the data from the entities (or call the respective methods on a Repository) should also call `S3Service` to remove such files from S3.

In my opinion, you should strive to keep the Services talking to each other whenever possible so that you keep your business logic in such a layer. Otherwise, you might end up with spaghetti code that is hard to read, maintain and change.

---

Another approach could be let the S3 deletion be event-driven. In this case, whenever you delete a `Post`, you would publish an event with the IDs of the images to delete or with the ID of the deleted `Post` (if with that you are able to find the images to delete on S3). This would decouple the deletion of the entities in the DB from the deletion of the images in S3. This would be my preferred approach.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. In my case, I am using JPA and the image tuples are removed by cascading and orphanRemoval options not directly by the service or repository layer.

Comment: So if I delete, for example, post, then images that are uploaded in that post are deleted by the system

Comment: In that case, whoever deletes `Post` must also trigger the deletion of the associated images from S3 by calling `S3Service`. As usual, it is important to have this `Post` deletion be done by one single class and not spread all over your code. Or you can follow an event-driven approach that I have added to my answer.